# App is crashing when selecting text of webview in Android 11

Tags: android, android-webview, android-appcompat, android-studio-3.0

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c000e
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:285)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1297)
       at org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:4)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl.n(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:1)
       at WJ.onCreateActionMode(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:8)
       at ka0.onCreateActionMode(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:2)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onCreateActionMode(DecorView.java:3842)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionMode(DecorView.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionModeForChild(DecorView.java:1354)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1048)
       at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:8359)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl.K(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:10)
       at Ga0.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:10)
       at Na0.i(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:4)
       at rS.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428010133:3)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: I have applied https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237587153 but did not work

Comment: getting similar crash issue in crashlytics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739227/how-to-fix-fatal-exception-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x20c003b