# how to fix Fatal Exception: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c003b DeviceFormFactor.java line 107 org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.a

Tags: android, resources

Getting this in crashlytics, not getting an idea where the problem would be.

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c003b
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:264)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1201)
   at org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.a(DeviceFormFactor.java:107)
   at R8.onCreateActionMode(R8.java:722)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onCreateActionMode(DecorView.java:2840)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionMode(DecorView.java:1012)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionModeForChild(DecorView.java:968)
  
   at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1033)
   at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:7774)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl.B(SelectionPopupControllerImpl.java:489)
   at di0.a(di0.java:1587)
   at Fl0.i(Fl0.java:259)
   at T6.run(T6.java:454)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8312)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

any suggestions on how to fix this?

whats the putpose of org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl class and org.chromium.content.browser.selection.SelectionPopupControllerImpl method?

can we guess what is actually happening or what has triggered this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if there's any resource in file exists only in -v24 etc. and not in base folder.

Comment: Ammar Abdullah how did you get that clue? its somewhat tedious task, but will do it.

Comment: For more info check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

Comment: `Caution: When defining an alternative resource, make sure you also define the resource in a default configuration. Otherwise, your app might encounter runtime exceptions when the device changes a configuration. For example, if you add a string to only values-en and not values, your app might encounter a Resource Not Found exception when the user changes the default system language.`

Comment: Should it not also hint about the activity or fragment or view  where the resource is getting used, can we get hint from the stack trace, i don't find it.